# Align fixed elements to screen on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

Fixed elements are aligned perfectly on desktop (`bottom` and `right` are aligned to the browser window). But on mobile the elements are aligned to the container size.

This is how it look on mobile (the black line represent the screen):

[image]

This is how I want it to look on mobile (the black line represent the screen):

[image]

Example code (In my real life application the canvas need to be larger than the viewport (hence the `150vh` and `150vw` size of the canvas)):

**html**

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fixedElement">I AM A FIXED ELEMENT</div>
    <div class="fixedElement2">I AM A FIXED ELEMENT 2</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**css**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 150vw;
  height: 150vh;
  background-color: orange;
}

.fixedElement {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  right: 200px;
}

.fixedElement2 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/siggmus/pen/XdEwEM)

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: by default position:fixed is relative to the viewport you need to adjust css according to your screen otherwise you have to change position:fixed to absolute form.

Comment: You should not use user-scalable="no". You are causing accessibility issues with this setting.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

or

```
html,body,.container{
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I was not clear enough in my question. I updated it now. Part of the problem is that the canvas needs to be larger that the viewport. I need some elements to stay fixed (the .fixedElement1 and .fixedElement2) while the "background" (.container) is scrollable.

Comment: @allegutta what if , if you replace following css 

.fixedElement {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  right:calc(200px + 50vw);
}

.fixedElement2 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:calc(50px + 50vh);
  left: 200px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following rule to the css of the body:

```
body {
   width: 100vw;
}
```

I created a codepen example that worked for me: [Example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/philippp/pen/JXLgpY/)

I hope that is what you searched for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it did not solve it (try to open the codepen example on your mobile)

Comment: I did and with your codepen it didn't work, but with mine it was fine. What mobile phone do you use? And did you open the full screen example?

Comment: Hmmm, I tried it in full screen on an iPhone 5S, with no luck. The elements are scrolling with the container.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing units there (vw and px).

The vw unit is relative to the width of the viewport. Setting this value to `150vw` makes your "canvas" (the div-container with class `container`) 150% wide. It extends the body or the viewport by 50% to the right.

Setting your fixed elements position values to a fixed unit `right: 200px` might work in some viewports but sure enough not in all. The wider the viewport the wider your container (150vw) but the 200px will always be the same.

Comment: Thanks. How would you have written the css for this layout (to work on desktop and mobile)?

Comment: There are two possible solutions:
you stop extending the canvas to 150% of the viewport as some commenters here already suggested and go with a width of `100vw` or `100%` or if you wanted to write nice(r) CSS just go without a width value for the div container with the class `container` in the first place.

Then you can position your fixed elements relative to that.

OR:
you set the position also relatively in `vw` where the value should be something above `right: 50vw` for the one and above `left: 50vw` for the other.

Comment: I see that I was not clear enough in my question. Part of the problem is that the canvas needs to be larger that the viewport. I need some elements to stay fixed (the `.fixedElement1` and `.fixedElement2`) while the "background" (`.container`) is scrollable. If you know what I mean?

Comment: Then `position: fixed` is the wrong approach. The elements should not scroll with the `.container`, right?

Comment: Wouldn't `position: absolute` for those elements make much more sense?